# Loading hidden HTML content into DIV from anchor link

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a group of links or buttons that will change the content of a div

```
 <p><button>EMPLOYEE NAME HERE</button></p>
 <p><button>EMPLOYEE NAME HERE</button></p>
 <p><button>EMPLOYEE NAME HERE</button></p>
 <p><button>EMPLOYEE NAME HERE</button></p>
```

Each employee has a different image and description but each div are the same size, the first employee will be shown by default as so to have no empty space but when the other 3 are selected the div is filled with the respective div according to it, then you can cycle through the profiles as you wish. Here is my div structure

```
<div id="employee">
</div>

<div id="employee1">
</div>

<div id="employee2">
</div>

<div id="employee3">
</div>

<div id="employee4">
</div>
```

Here is the javascript im trying to use

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('button').bind('click', function() {
$('div#employee').html($('div#employee' + ($(this).index()+1)).html());
});
</script>
```

All the help i can get would be really appreciated, im not that great at java script and really need a hand with this. Im not sure i explained myself very well but i did try.

Just to confirm, all the divs are hidden until the button is pressed, then the div for that employee will appear, except the first profile which will appear by default on load.

Thanks for your help in advance.

James

Comment: What is the problem that you face?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simplified example. It may or may not be the most efficient, but it should do what you want. This is assuming that you're pre-loading all of the content into the divs, but just hiding it at the beginning. If you are wanting to dynamically load the content, then you'll want to use some [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**HTML**

```
<p><button id="button1">EMPLOYEE One</button></p>
<p><button id="button2">EMPLOYEE Two</button></p>
 <p><button id="button3">EMPLOYEE Three</button></p>
 <p><button id="button4">EMPLOYEE Four</button></p>
 <p><button id="button5">EMPLOYEE Five</button></p>
<br/><br/>
<div id="employee1" class="employeeInfo">
    Employee1 is a good employee
</div>

<div id="employee2" class="employeeInfo">
    Emloyee2 is an alright employee
</div>

<div id="employee3" class="employeeInfo">
    Emloyee3 is the best employee ever!
</div>

<div id="employee4" class="employeeInfo">
    Employee4 is not a very good employee
</div>

<div id="employee5" class="employeeInfo">
    Employee5 is about to be fired
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $("#employee1").show();

    $("button").on("click", function(){
        $(".employeeInfo").hide();
        $("#employee"+String($(this).attr("id").substring(6))).show();
        // OR if you don't want to have to give IDs to the buttons
        // $("#employee"+String($("button").index($(this))+1)).show();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.employeeInfo {
    display: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6he46/)

Comment: Nice work. I also was getting the ids migrated from the divs to the buttons, what I struggled on was isolating the id of the button (which I worked out but what stumped me was running around to find the div with the same id.  Good work!

Comment: Thanks @FrankTudor I've updated the Javascript to include an option that uses `.index()`, which the OP was attempting to use. This would allow you to forgo giving IDs to the button elements, although I always suggest giving elements IDs. Plus, grabbing the ID of `$(this)` is almost certainly faster than having to look up the index of `$(this)` within a set of elements (although I haven't benchmarked that).

Comment: @jwhiting81 Great. Since it worked for you, do make sure to mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: How do i do that? Sorr, noob

Comment: @jwhiting81 Click the check mark under the up/down arrows next to the answer.